# JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0

Tags: c#, mysql, json, asp.net-web-api, localhost

I tried looking into the similar threads but I can't seem to find solution for my problem.

I have ASP.NET WEB API and client UWP app that communicates to the localhost database through that API.

Here is the code to get data (client app):

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = "";
            Task task = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                response = await client.GetStringAsync(App.BaseUri); // sends GET request
            });
            task.Wait(); // Wait

            List<Product> ProductList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(response); //ERROR HERE XX

            listViewAPI.ItemsSource = ProductList; // Bind the list
        }
```

My BaseUri in App file looks like this:

```
public static Uri BaseUri = new Uri("http://localhost:58834/api/Product/"); // base API URL; ProductController
```

Here is the controller from API:

```
using ASPNetWebAPI.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace ASPNetWebAPI.Controllers
{
[Route("api/Product")]
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    // GET: api/product
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Product> Get() 
    {
        return Model.ReadAllSQLProducts();
    }

}
}
```

Here is the Model from API:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ASPNetWebAPI.Models
{
public class Model
{

    // Example data source
    private static List<Product> products = new List<Product>()
    {

    };

    // R part of CRUD
    public static List<Product> ReadAllSQLProducts()
    {
        return products;
    }

}

}
```

Here is the actual Product class from API:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ASPNetWebAPI.Models
{
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }

}
}
```

And here is the connection string from Web.config of API:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="ProductConn" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ProductDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"/>  
  </connectionStrings> 
...
</configuration>
```

I explicitly told in connectionstring which db to connect to as I have multiple databases in localhost.

I cannot resolve the error that says:

> Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>   An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Comment: What does `response` look like? sounds like its XML not JSON.

Comment: I forgot to say, that in the db there already is one record.

Comment: @AlexK. How can I check this? This is my first attempt to using API and JSON.

Comment: Put `http://localhost:58834/api/Product/` in a browser and check the result. Is it JSON or XML?

Comment: @DanWilson It actually opens a default ASP.NET welcome page with few links

Comment: Then perhaps you have not authenticated with the site and are getting HTML. You need to work out how to authenticate with the API and send the correct headers or cookies when making the request.

Comment: I followed the instructions from this tutorial: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1018082/ASP-NET-Web-API-RESTful-CRUDs-and-Windows-native